# Exact sequence of noetherian local ring quotient

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Is it true that for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $R$, and $R'=R/\mathfrak{p}$, we have an exact sequence

$$
0\to \mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{m}^n\to R/\mathfrak{m}^n \to R'/\mathfrak{m}'^n\to 0
$$

for any $n$? I want to prove $l(R/\mathfrak{m}^n)\geq l(R'/\mathfrak{m}'^n)$ where $l$ is the length of the module. Is this method okay?

Comment: Not sure how you want to define this sequence. What injective homomorphism you want to define $\mathfrak{p}\to R/\mathfrak{m}^n$? And anyway, I think you should just try to use the correspondence theorem for the exercise.

Comment: @Mark just the inclusion modulo $\mathfrak{m}^n$ is fine. It is the other homomorphism which I can't figure out.

I'll look into the correspondence theorem thanks.

Comment: But why this inclusion will be injective? For example, if $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{m}$ and $n=1$ then it will be trivial, not injective. Anyway, using the correspondence theorem shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Good point. So perhaps to make my point about the lengths, I should start with $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{m}^n$, which makes everything consistent I believe, since $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{m}^n$ is a prime ideal in $A/\mathfrak{m}^n$. I'll make the edit

Comment: @coolpenguin Note that $\mathfrak{p}$ does not contain $\mathfrak{m}^n$ unless $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{m}$. You want $\mathfrak{p}/(\mathfrak{p} \cap \mathfrak{m}^n)$.